# Why this Angular 4 custom validator return a Promise or an Observable? What is the exact logic?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-promise, angular-observable

I am very new in **Angular 4** and I am not so into **JavaScript\TypeScript** and I have the following doubt about this example found in a tutorial.

It is related to the implementation of a custom form validator but my doubts are more about the **Observable** and **Promise** objects.

So I have something like this:

```
import {Form, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class CustomValidators {
  static asyncInvalidProjectName(control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (control.value === 'Testproject') {
          resolve({'invalidProjectName': true});
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      }, 2000);
    })
    return promise;
  }
}
```

The **asyncInvalidProjectName()** method implements the logic of my custom validator.

My doubts are:

1) It seems to me that this method can return a **Promise** object OR an **Observable** object.

Why? It seems to me that it always return a **Promise** object that represents if the input in the form is valid or not. Why in the signature it seems that can return also an **Observable**?

2) What exactly represents a **Promise** object and what are the difference with an **Observable**? (from what I know an Observable is used to react to event change)

Comment: maybe so that validation can be done asynchronously? On the server perhaps. As for the promise vs observable, google can help you find plenty of resources.

Comment: even in the example you gave you can see that there's an setTImeout and the result of the validation will be shown later..

Comment: so do you want to know the difference between observable and promise?